# Why does calling natsorted not modify my list?

Tags: python, natsort

```
from natsort import natsorted

filelist=[]
filelist=os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Amit\\Downloads\\Compressed\\trainigVid")
natsorted(filelist)
print filelist
```

I am getting following output

```
['1.avi', '10.avi', '11.avi', '12.avi', '13.avi', '14.avi', '15.avi',   '16.avi', '17.avi', '18.avi', '19.avi', '2.avi', '20.avi', '21.avi', '22.avi', '23.avi', '24.avi', '3.avi', '4.avi', '5.avi', '6.avi', '7.avi', '8.avi', '9.avi']
```

I want this list to be naturally sorted like

```
[1.avi, 2.avi, 3.avi.....]
```

I am stuck,please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`natsorted` returns the newly sorted list, it does not modify the original list in place. This means you should use:

```
filelist = natsorted(filelist)
```

to get that return value.

Comment: If you really want to sort in-place, use `from natsort import natsort_key; filelist.sort(key=natsort_key)`.

Comment: @SethMMorton All I wanted was to sort that list, but I will definitely try your solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os

filelist = os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Amit\\Downloads\\Compressed\\trainigVid")
out = []

for s in sorted(filelist, key=lambda x:int(os.path.splitext(x)[0])):
    out.append(s)

print out
```

**Demo:**

```
['1.avi', '2.avi', '3.avi', '4.avi', '5.avi', '6.avi', '7.avi', '8.avi', '9.avi', '10.avi', '11.avi', '12.avi', '13.avi', '14.avi', '15.avi', '16.avi', '17.avi', '18.avi', '19.avi', '20.avi', '21.avi', '22.avi', '23.avi', '24.avi']
```

Comment: Thank you,but Vouissour gave simpler solution!

Comment: Okay, this is just my solution without use `natsorted` :)